# Installing tensorflow-gpu broke tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow cpu via anaconda and after using the command

conda install tensorflow-gpu

I got the following error message

> File "", line 1, in 
>   runfile('C:/Users/g/Desktop/Masters-Project/Gaussian ROC
>   example/Neural Network Worked Example.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/g/Desktop/Masters-Project/Gaussian ROC example')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/g/Desktop/Masters-Project/Gaussian ROC example/Neural
>   Network Worked Example.py", line 7, in 
>       from keras.models import Sequential as sequential
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from . import utils
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from . import conv_utils
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       from .. import backend as K
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py",
>   line 89, in 
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py",
>   line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

I'm not even trying to use the GPU at the minute since it hasn't arrived yet and this is CPU only mode, I'm very confused as to what could be wrong.

Comment: have you tried removing the GPU version of tf using `conda remove tensorflow-gpu` then reinstalling the standard version? You won't be able to use the GPU version without the correct GPU hardware and NVidia libraries installed.

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow-gpu` is not just an additional module for tensorflow but rather a separate version of `tensorflow`. When you installed `tensorflow-gpu` the `tensorflow` package got uninstalled. Now loading the tensorflow-gpu version fails, since you probably are missing all of the CUDA libraries. Just remove the `tensorflow-gpu` package and reinstall the old `tensorflow` package again until you actually have a CUDA enabled GPU.

Comment: I have CUDA but not the CUDA enabled GPU yet. I assumed it would at least run then not detect a GPU.